# How to force Network Manager to rescan connections?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, bash, networkmanager

How to force Network Manager in Ubuntu to rescan wireless connections?

After closing my laptop, network manager does not see new wireless connections. Is there any bash command to force rescan? `sudo service network-manager restart` does not help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
sudo iwlist interface scan
```

Where *interface* is the name of your wireless card, e. g. wlan0

Comment: use sudo ifconfig to find out the name of the "interface"

Comment: Do you really need to use sudo for this?

Comment: @Morten: Yes, we do need `sudo`. "Triggering scanning is a privileged operation (root only) and normal users can only read left-over scan results." (`man iwlist`)

Comment: This answer does not use NetworkManager. See @Davide's answer which does.

Answer (score 29):

Try

```
nmcli device wifi rescan
```

and

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

to see available networks

Comment: Best answer. Without using sudo.

Comment: This should be the accetpted answer. It is, after all, the "command-line tool for controlling NetworkManager". It gives a nice graphical command-line output if you specify `list` (or no argument at all).

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04 and newer, restarting NetworkManager with sytemctl works (at least after scanning the networks manually with `iwlist`):

```
# Find the name of the network interface, e.g. wlan0 or wlp3s0
ip addr show      

# Scan for WLAN networks (replace wlan0 by the correct interface)
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

# Restart Ubuntu’s Network Manager so it reloads the Access Point list
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 2):

I have too low reputation to elaborate under Davide's answer so I decided to add a new answer. Create a file `/usr/share/applications/rescan.desktop` with the following contents to be able to easily launch a rescan through the dashboard:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Rescan wifi
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/nmcli device wifi rescan
Terminal=false
Icon=network-wireless
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Network;System
Name[en]=Rescan wifi
Name[en_US]=Rescan wifi
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` should work...

Answer (score 1):

Simply deactivating and reactivating your wireless module would be a workaround.

Comment: -1. Though this naively seems like a decent solution, it eventually led me to hard-block my network card for the weekend.

Comment: I do this by enabling and disabling the airplace mode using my laptop keyboard's function key shortcut

Answer (score 1):

The checked answer is incorrect for most situations. Only nmcli controls NM.

The first thing to do is to check for NM's radio status:

```
$ nmcli r
```

This will let you know if the wifi radio is enabled.

If not, then:

```
$ nmcli r wifi on
```

You can then confirm the result:

```
$ sudo nmcli device wifi list
```